# How to make a video background of a div and svg?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this video a background of a div and svg too, just like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sLU1.png)

I tryed:

```
<section id="home" style="position: relative;background: #1d5867b5;">
        <div class="py-5">
            <div class="d-flex p-5 flex-column ">
                <span style="max-width: 110ch;">
                    <h1 class="display-3 font-weight-bold mb-4 text-white" style="margin: 0px;">Propagando conhecimento que transforma através da Educação Online.</h1>

                </span>

                <button class="btn btn-warning font-weight-bold text-info w-25 p-2" type="button">
                    <span>CONHEÇA O QUE FAZEMOS</span>

                    <i class=""></i>

                </button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <video class="home-video" src="https://www.youni.com.br/img/video.mp4" width="100%" height="100%"></video>

</section>
<svg viewBox="0 50 500 80" style="position: relative; margin-top: -100px;">
  <path class="wave-color1" d="M0.00,92.27 C216.83,192.92 304.30,8.39 500.00,109.03 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z" stroke="none"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you add your code? What you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get acquainted with the site and post a [mre] so we can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it before [here](http://www.advanttechnology.com/) 
You will need to use the html5 video tag and set the whole div as fixed position with z-index value less than any other div at the same section.

here's example

```
<video preload="" muted="" poster="URL.jpg" autoplay="" loop="" width="100%">

            <source src="URL.mp4" type="video/mp4">

            <source src="URL.ogv" type="video/ogv">

            <source src="URL.webm" type="video/webm">

        </video>
```

and for the CSS use

```
video {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background-size: cover;
```

}

and make sure the main div is set to overflow: hidden;

Comment: Please provide a solution with code not with link to another site. [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)